# KnockoutJS, using subscribable. callbackTarget

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, publish-subscribe

I want to implement a simple pub-sub in my application, so KO subscribable seems to be promising.

I have the the following code.

```
var announcer = new ko.subscribable();

var s1 = announcer.subscribe(function(val){
    console.log('subscriber1: ' + val);
}, null, 'news');

var s2 = announcer.subscribe(function(val){
    console.log('subscriber2: ' + val);
}, null, 'gossip');

var s3 = announcer.subscribe(function(val){
    console.log('subscriber3: ' + val);
}, null, 'news');
```

Publish in the "news" channel

```
announcer.notifySubscribers('good news', 'news')

/* Outputs: */

subscriber1: good news
subscriber3: good news
```

Publish in the "gossip" channel

```
announcer.notifySubscribers('hipster news', 'gossip')

/* Outputs: */

subscriber2: hipster news
```

So far, it seems to work...

My question is:

**What is the second parameter that subscribable.subscribe expects?**

Knockout website never speaks about it, so I went to the code and found this:

```
subscribe: function (callback, callbackTarget, event) {
    event = event || defaultEvent;
    var boundCallback = callbackTarget ? callback.bind(callbackTarget) : callback;

var subscription = new ko.subscription(this, boundCallback, function () {
        ko.utils.arrayRemoveItem(this._subscriptions[event], subscription);
    }.bind(this));
```

It is obvious that my implementation of pub/sub works because I am not passing a callbackTarget, so *callback* is used instead.

Bonus questions:

**When should we use a *callbackTarget*?**

**Can anyone provide an example of its usage?**

Comment: Okay both answers are cool... so the mysterious "bind" method is present in every javascript function since JavaScript 1.8.5.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second parameter of subscribe function is used for setting context of `this`. If do not want to use `this` inside callback function you can pass null.

Comment: But if callbackTarget is set, then ko will execute: callback.bind(callbackTarget)... won't that fail? I don't know about any "bind" method that is prototype of function

Comment: No, it will not. Inside bind it will call your callback using js apply\call function.

Answer (score 1):

Don't take my word as solemn because I have never used this capability but I believe I can answer your question anyways...

The callbackTarget is the context that you want to bind to, so if you are subscribing from outside your viewmodel you can still bind to that context by passing it in -

**When should we use a callbackTarget?**

When you are binding to a context outside of that context - ie binding to the context of a viewmodel when you have multiple view models.

**Can anyone provide an example of its usage?**

Example from - http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html

```
postbox.subscribe(callback, target, topic);

postbox.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    this.latestTopic(newValue);
}, vm, "mytopic");
```

Where the function is the callback, the callbackTarget is 'vm', and the topic is 'mytopic'

Comment: Thanks, I've landed in the knockmeout article before, but I was confused because I didn't know that bind() was in the Function prototype, so I thought that you need some special object instead of a simple function.